# Can signals be used directly in conditional statements in lieu of comparison to 0/1?

Tags: vhdl

Can a signal (of type std_logic) be used directly as the condition in an 'if' statement? For example, can I write

`if (A and not B) then`

instead of

`if (A = '1' and B = '0') then` ?

I realize something wonky may happen if the signals take other values like 'Z', but aside from that sort of thing, is this syntactically valid? The first one seems much briefer, especially for more complicated logical expressions.

**Addendum:** What worries me is whether the argument of the "if" is of the right type, if that matters. I'm from a programming (C++) background, so I routinely use things like `if( my_int )` instead of `if( my_int != 0 )` where `my_int` is implicitly cast to a bool. Just wasn't sure if the same thing is really going on here. I presume the result of the VHDL comparison `A = '1'` is an abstract logical value ("true" or "false") and not some concrete std_logic value.

Comment: What does your synthesis or simulation tool say?

Comment: @asdfex : I'm afraid this is theoretical for now. I'm reading my way through Free Range VHDL and in doing some of the exercises this occurred to me. I did indeed think to break out ModelSim and see what compiles and what doesn't, but I wondered even if it compiles if it is really the same (except for the cases I referred to). I'm from a C++ programming background, so I'm trying to be careful and not fall into traps like this.

Comment: I don't see why not. How else are you supposed to do something like compare something like integer signals against anything other than a fixed value? I would type that in without a second thought but can't remember the last time I did. That said, I would not use the first one since it is less verbose. This ain't C.

Comment: Also, it doesn't compile. It synthesizes.

Comment: VHDL doesn't implicitly cast anything. It is strongly typed. VHDL has roots in Ada.

Comment: @DKNguyen : Hmm, ModelSim uses the term "compile" explicitly. But I understand what you mean. Thanks for the info, I'm new to the VHDL world.

Comment: @MPW Yes, Modelsim DOES compile : then it simulates. It is not a synthesis tool. Once your design is working in Modelsim, synthesis (e.g. using Vivado or Synplify) is the next step on the way to a working FPGA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Signals of type Boolean : yes of course.

And you can happily use boolean types for synthesis, making life simpler, especially in internal signals, cases where 'Z' and 'X' etc cannot happen.

Signals of type std_logic : yes in VHDL-2008 mode.

It's one of the additions I least like in VHDL-2008 because it implicitly equates '1' and TRUE, and '0' and FALSE. If this is combined with negative logic or active-low signals (as are often used  for resets, RESET_N, imposed by external requirements) the result is an atrocious mess like

```
if RESET_N then 
  -- non-reset case
else
  -- reset case
end if;
```

Even worse, sometimes the signal is active low but named RESET.
In such cases, please PLEASE please write out `if RESET_N = '0' then` longhand...

In other cases, use judgment whether the shorter implicit version, or the longer explicit version, will make more sense to the next guy. Both have their uses.

Comment: It's referred to as an implicit conditional operator.